# Pulsar OIDC protocol_version error with TLSv1.3 restricted Keycloak

Tags: tls1.3, apache-pulsar

We've setup a Pulsar 3.1.0 cluster with OIDC authentication. This works fine until we try to connect to a Keycloak instance that is restricted to only accepts TLSv1.3, then we get a `fatal alert: protocol_version` error.

Debugging the TLS handshake, the initial communication goes well, with both `ClientHello.extensions.supported_versions.versions` and  `ServerHello.extensions.supported_versions.selected_version` having `TLSv1.3` as value.

The problem arises after the log says "org.apache.pulsar.functions.worker.Workerutils - Create Pulsar Admin to service ..." and the `AsyncHttpClient` starts its TLS handshake.

The failing ClientHello has TLSv1.2 in `ClientHello.extensions.supported_versions.versions`.

We've tried to set different Pulsar runtime options using PULSAR_EXTRA_OPTS to control protocol version but they don't seem to be honoured for that case. We've verified on the Pulsar server that the PULSAR_EXTRA_OPTS environment variables are set.

The runtime options we added to Pulsar were: `PULSAR_EXTRA_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3 -Dhttps.client.protocols=TLSv1.3 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.3 -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake"`

Is it possible to force the TLS version in some other way or is it known problem with a potential workaround?

Unfortunately, we don't have the customers permission to share any logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-Dorg.asynchttpclient.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.3` to `PULSAR_EXTRA_OPTS` makes it work. Unfortunately this is undocumented.